# Calculate the path integral $\int x^3dx + y^3dy + z^3dz$ over the curve $\{z=x^2+y^2,\, y+z=3\}$

Tags: integration, parametric, surface-integrals

I've plotted the [curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B85Sl.png). I suppose I need to parametrize it, e.g. $\{x = r\cos{\alpha},\,y = r\sin{\alpha}-0.5,\,z = 3.5 - r\sin{\alpha}\}$, but substituting the values of $x,y,z$ into the integral yields long cubic formulas. Maybe it's possible to apply Stokes Theorem here, but I haven't found much information on how to do it with parametrized curves. Is there any simpler way to compute this integral? ($r = \sqrt{13}/2$ is a constant)

Comment: Have you tried to find curl of the vector field? What does that tell you?

Comment: You should also have a value for $r=\sqrt{3.25}=\frac{\sqrt{13}}2.$

Comment: @MathLover I've tried computing the divergence of the vector field $3*(x^2+y^2+z^2)$. Maybe I can use the divergence theorem in spherical coordinates?

Comment: You are supposed to find line integral of the vector field over the given intersection curve which is boundary of the paraboloid surface. Use Stokes' theorem. Find curl first.

Comment: and do you know about conservative vector fields? Anyway find curl first and then we can converse more.

Comment: @MathLover sorry, I'm not very familiar with the topic. I did some reading on Stokes Theorem, so now the question seems rather stupid. The curl is zero, so by Stokes Theorem, this integral should also be zero.

Comment: Yes the curl is zero and so it is a conservative vector field. So its line integral over a closed curve will be zero as the line integrals of conservative vector fields are path independent. Alternatively you can state that it is zero by Stokes' theorem.

Comment: @MathLover Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curl of the vector field $({x^3,y^3,z^3})$ is zero, so the vector field is conservative. Path integrals over closed curves in conservative fields are 0, so the **answer is 0**.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2+y^2=3-y \implies x^2+\left(y+\frac12\right)^2=\frac{13}4$$

Let $x(t)=\frac{\sqrt{13}}2\cos(t)$ and $y(t)=\frac{\sqrt{13}}2\sin(t)-\frac12$, so it follows that $z(t)=3-y(t)=\frac72-\frac{\sqrt{13}}2\sin(t)$. You get the curve of intersection for $0\le t\le2\pi$.

Denote this parameterization of the path $C$ by $\vec r(t)$; that is,

$$\vec r(t)=x(t)\,\vec\imath+y(t)\,\vec\jmath+z(t)\,\vec k$$

with derivative

$$\frac{\mathrm d\vec r(t)}{\mathrm dt}=x'(t)\,\vec\imath+y'(t)\,\vec\jmath+z'(t)\,\vec k$$

Denoting the given inherent vector field by $\vec F(x,y,z)$, the line integral over $C$ is then

$$\int_C\vec F(x,y,z)\cdot\mathrm d\vec r=\int_C\vec F(\vec r(t))\cdot\frac{\mathrm d\vec r(t)}{\mathrm dt}\,\mathrm dt=\int_0^{2\pi}g(t)\,\mathrm dt$$

where $g(t)$ is short for

$$-\frac{211\sqrt{13}}8\cos(t)+\frac{39\sqrt{13}}8\cos^3(t)+\frac{4069}{32}\cos(t)\sin(t)-\frac{507}{32}\cos^3(t)\sin(t)-\frac{117\sqrt{13}}8\cos(t)\sin^2(t)+\frac{507}{32}\cos(t)\sin^3(t)$$

and whose antiderivative is easy enough to find. But this method is overkill, and you should use shortcuts (Stokes' theorem, checking that $\vec F$ is conservative) when you can.